# grab() function in seq and seqr in UVM

Tags: uvm

The grab function could be found both in `uvm_sequence_base` and `uvm_sequencer_base`, the explanation make me so confused about the lock and grab.

I think the sequence is like the flow water, and the sequencer is the valve ,only sequencer could be blocked or opened .

Am I right? please say anything about the grab() both in sequence and sequencer.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using both for various situations, here's my observation**strong text**

Let's assume 4 streams of sequences waiting for the sequencer to grant access
S1,S2,S3,S4 (each containing 10 subsequences)

1)If grab/ungrab is used for only ONE of the sequences, say S2. Regardless of how arbitration is set, S2 will get access first. All the subsequences of S2 will be passed followed by other ones. Other sequences will be executed depending on the arbitration setting.

2)If lock/unlock is used for only ONE of the sequences, say S3. It will wait for its turn for the sequencer access, and all the subsequences will be executed one after the other.

Order of arrival-> S1,S2,S3,S4

assuming arbitration is SEQ_ARB_FIFO (Default)

execution -> S1.seq1 -> S2.seq1 -> S3.seq1 -> S3.seq2 -> .......-> S3.seq10 -> S4.seq1 -> S1.seq2 -> S2.seq2 -> ......->S4.seq10

3. Multiple lock/grab will be given priority and the queued ones will be given access in the FIFO order regardless of the arbitration settings

eg1: Order of arrival-> S1,S2,S3,S4

S1: lock/unlock

S3: grab/ungrab

assuming arbitration is SEQ_ARB_FIFO (Default)

execution -> S1.seq1 -> S1.seq2 -> ....S3.seq1 -> S3.seq2 -> .......-> S3.seq10 -> S2.seq1 -> S4.seq1 -> S2.seq2 -> ......->S4.seq10

eg2: Order of arrival-> S1,S2,S3,S4

S1: lock/unlock

S3: lock/unlock

assuming arbitration is SEQ_ARB_FIFO (Default)

execution -> S1.seq1 -> S1.seq2 -> ....S3.seq1 -> S3.seq2 -> .......-> S3.seq10 -> S2.seq1 -> S4.seq1 -> S2.seq2 -> ......->S4.seq10

Answer (score 0):

`grab()` and `lock()` are very similar.  The only difference is that a `grab()` request is put at the front of the sequencer arbitration queue, and a `lock()` request is put at the back of sequencer arbitration queue.

This blog has one of the best explanations I have found about how to use the UVM sequencer built-in `grab` and `lock` functions:

http://sagar5258.blogspot.com/2017/02/